# Поиск mongodb не работает (pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

В `ru_codes` лежит json размером 40 мб, закидываю его в дб `codes.put(json.dumps(ru_codes), encoding='utf-8')`,

И хочу вывести результат поиска, который лежит в `cur`.

```
cur = db.codes.find({'countries': {'004': {'title': 'Грузия'}}})
x = []
for i in cur:
    x.append(i)
print(x)`
```

Однако массив `x` всегда почему-то пустой.
Вот целый код:

```
def create_db(ru_codes):
    '''This method creates and insert document with station codes'''
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client['codes']
    codes = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    codes.put(json.dumps(ru_codes), encoding='utf-8')
    cur = db.codes.find({'countries': {'004': {'title': 'Грузия'}}})
    x = []
    for i in cur:
         x.append(i)
    print(x)
```

Comment: 1) А добавляется ли документ в коллекцию? 2) А содержит ли документ искомую информацию 3) А успевает ли добавиться документ до того момента, когда Вы делаете запрос (вопрос из мира Javascript)?